# Warning displayed when adding solution to Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I'm just getting to grips with TFS 2010 (never had any luck with TFS 2008) and I'm trying to add my first solution into TFS. However I am getting the following warning message:

> The project that you are attempting to add to source control may cause other source control users to have difficulty opening this solution or getting newer versions of it. To avoid this problem, add the project from a location below the binding root of the other source controlled projects in the solution.

Can someone explain to me what this means and how to resolve it? This warning is displayed when right clicking on the solution in Solution Explorer and selecting "Add to Source Control".

Comment: Just ran into the same problem; now I know :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your solution folder structure should resemble:

```
Solution Root folder
├── .sln solution file       
│
├── Project1 folder
│   └── Project1.csproj   (or .vbproj)
│
├── Project2 folder
│   └── Project2.csproj   (or .vbproj)
.
.
.
```

Comment: How would this structure cater for two solutions which share one project between them (that project being outside of the root) binding for either solution?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: having a sensible solution/project structure has little to do with what source control you use. Just because a tool lets you do something doesn't mean it's a good idea!

Comment: @Mitch your source control should not limit you is what I'm saying.  It should not get in your way.  I've used both TFS and subversion and I can tell you I am not alone when I say TFS bitches about crap it shouldn't and so the overall experience is friction, not frictionless.  A good source control is both powerful but makes things easy.  TFS is not..and the only way you will see this is if you get out of the mind set that you MUST use everything Microsoft and try something different for once in terms of source control if you are an MS shop.  Many MS shops hate TFS for the reasons I state.

Comment: It's totally ridiculous that anyone has to even post about this problem in TFS.  You should be able to add folders anywhere and the source control should have no problem with that.  The tool should work FOR you not against you or force ridiculous patterns.

Comment: "should be able to add folders anywhere and the source control should have no problem with that" - that's not correct. Having a well known, consistent structure is a good idea, and one that is pretty much universally accepted. Adding bits from all over the place is a really poor idea. Convention over configuration and all that...

Comment: I never said not having a good structure.  Well known?  Do you  mean across all TFS users?  That is nice for TFS users but you should not be forced to have a specific arrangement or pattern.  The team should be able to come up with their own convention without TFS bitching aobut it or saying no.  I did not say adding from all over.  There are other structures that make more sense and no it doesn't make sense to have everything in a tree necessarily...believe me.

Answer (score 7):

As described in this Visual Studio forum post (link below), the basic issue is that a project in the solution is outside of the sub-tree that the solution itself is in. This can possibly lead to problems if another user maps the different subtrees differently in his workspaces than the user that is checking in. The cross-tree references will no longer work. The dialog is only a warning, but can be continued if you know your team doesn't split up the code tree with complex workspace mappings.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29579a28-9de0-4fc6-a253-b38191aa4fdc/must-projects-be-added-under-binding-root-of-solution?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Answer (score 5):

For me it was like this that I tried to add the solution from another location already. I then had to clean the workspace which was created for the other location.

For Visual Studio 2013 you can find the workspace settings under:

```
File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces...
```

1. On the `Manage Workspaces` dialog select your workspace you work with
2. Hit `Edit...`.
3. On the `Edit Workspace <yourworkspacename>` dialog
4. clear the **"wrong"** location

Try to add the solution again.

Answer (score 0):

The following issue can sympomatically manifest the error you reported.  Remember, referenced assemblies need not be in any specific location in either TFS or in the file system of your workstation.

An underlying problem is that some types of projects default to the "*Client*" version of the targeted .NET Framework.  The *Client* versions strip out assemblies that are usually not used in deployable projects.  Furthermore, any assembly your project references must also not reference assemblies omitted by the *Client* profile.

Simply change the Target framework setting of your project to the full framework version.

Check out my blog post, regarding this issue: 
http://thecurlybrace.blogspot.com/2010/09/visual-studio-wears-sabots.html