# Binding projects to other source controlled projects in the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, source-control-explorer

[image: Error message]

I am getting an error within TFS which I can not resolve no matter what I try.

The attached image of the error is pretty self explanatory!

Has anyone ever come across this error, and if so, how is it fixed?

Comment: You need to [ensure that your solution folder structure][1] is correct. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/934300

Answer (score 0):

This error is generally a result of a source code folder being outside of the workspace mapping.

For example, if you map **$/MyProject** to **C:\Source\MyProject** and you then attempt to check something in with the following folder structure:

```
C:\Source\
    MyProject\ 
        MyProject.sln
    MyTests
        MyTests.csproj
```

Since the "MyTests" folder lies outside of the workspace mapping, it will not be properly added to version control.

To resolve the issue, ensure the workspace mappings are setup correctly. For example, map **$/MyProject** to **C:\Source\MySolution** and setup the folder structure as follows:

```
C:\Source\
    MySolution\
        MyProject\ 
            MyProject.sln
        MyTests
            MyTests.csproj
```

By mapping to a common "root" folder, everything is picked up by the workspace mapping when adding it to version control.

Hope this helps.