# SVN folders in Azure devops

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, devops

Completely new with Azure Devops so would appreciate some guidance to get onto the right track. Installed Azure Devops Express on our local server and can log in. I have Visual Studio 2013 and was able to connect to the Devops instance, created a project and a local workspace. Everything is stored locally so i dont need to use Github.

1. Coming from a SVN background so how do i have similar folders such as branches, tag and trunk? Or what is the equivalent of these folders?
2. How could i force everyone to check in their code at the end of the day?
3. I added a project to an empty solution. I decided to test a check in and received the below warning
   [image]
   So what would be the correct way to add an existing C# class library project to the repo?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply/answer. I havent fully tried your solution but as soon as i do i will respond and mark as answer if it resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot and description.

Seem you are using **TFVC** as source control in TFS/Azure DevOps.

1. DinnerNow folder structure in Source Control Explorer

[image]

As the illustration shows,you can still use folders to organize branches within a project's version control hierarchy. However, folders and branches have a different appearance and different capabilities. When you right-click a folder or branch and click Properties, you display different information and different functionality.

You could view the branch structure in visual studio from Hierarchy window. 
 [image]

And easily convert a folder to a branch, more details please kindly refer this official tutorial--[Branch folders and files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=azure-devops)

2. While there is no way to force these kind of check-ins. You could not force them to do this, it is part of a process. I think you could set up a outlook meeting everyday to remind team members to do this.
3. You could take a look at the replies in this similar question: [Warning displayed when adding solution to Team Foundation Server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934263/warning-displayed-when-adding-solution-to-team-foundation-server-2010)

> The  issue is that **a project in the solution is outside of the
>   sub-tree that the solution itself is in**. This can possibly lead to
>   problems if another user maps the different subtrees differently in
>   his workspaces than the user that is checking in. The cross-tree
>   references will no longer work. The dialog is only a warning, but can
>   be continued if you know your team doesn't split up the code tree with
>   complex workspace mappings

.